# Scale command not applied to plot

Tags: r, ggplot2

The scale does not change the way I want and the way I wrote in the code. Why is that? Can someone help? My goal is to have a tick and label for every year on the x axis and a scale from -6 to 3 on the y axis, also including ticks and labels.

```
Periode <- as.Date(website$Datum)
Index <-  website$KonSens

datebreaks <- seq(as.Date("1998-03-31"), as.Date("2022-06-30"), by = "1 month")

plot.Website <- 
  ggplot(data = website, aes(x = Periode, y = Index)) +
  scale_x_date(breaks = datebreaks) +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(-6,3,1), labels = c("-6", "-5", "-4", "-3", "-2", "-1", "0", "1", "2", "3"), limits = c(-6,4), n.breaks = 10)+
  theme(axis.text = element_text(color = "black", face = "bold", size = 10),
        axis.line.y = element_line(color = "black", size = 2),
        axis.line.x = element_blank(),
        axis.title = element_text(color = "black", face = "bold"),
        axis.title.y = element_text(angle = 180)) +
  geom_line(aes(y = Index), color = "#7AA489",size = 1.5) +
  geom_point(shape = 21, color = "#003478", fill = "#7AA489", size = 2.5, stroke = 1)


ggplotly(plot.Website, dynamicTicks = TRUE) %>%
  rangeslider(borderwidth = 1)
```

[image: The breaks are not the same as in the code, wether on the x nor y axis]

Comment: The breaks are wrong with the ```ggplotly()```, are they also wrong in the ```ggplot()``` that you save in your ```plot.Website```?  Also! ```scale_y_continuous()``` has an argument ```limits``` and an argument ```breaks```. ```limits``` determines the total lenght of your axis, while ```breaks``` allows you to specify the distance between the axis ticks.

Comment: they are correct in the ggplot() but not in the ggplotly(). And for the y axis I does'nt adapt to changes I make in limits or breaks.

Comment: I am not too familiar with ggplotly, but ggplot2 makes a static image with ```limits and breaks```. The ```dynamicTicks = TRUE``` probably overrules the limit and/or break rules from your ggplot2 plot.

Answer (score 1):

Plotly may ignore you regardless of what you do because it looks like you are asking for almost 300 tick labels on the x-axis. However, when you use `ggplotly`, date fields become character fields. (I don't know if this is from `ggplot` or if it's a Plotly-ism.)

After rendering the `ggplotly` object, you can replace the `x` in each trace and replace the majority of the arguments for `layout.xaxis`. Alternatively, you may find it to be a lot easier if you create this in Plotly, to begin with.

I've added the data I used because your question is not reproducible. It looks like you're new to SO; welcome to the community! If you want great answers quickly, it's best to make all questions reproducible. For example, sample data from the output of `dput()` or `reprex::reprex()`. Check it out: [making R reproducible questions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269).

In the following code, the only parts you need to create the plot without the aesthetics are the first two piped: `plot_ly()` and `add_lines()`.

I added comments to explain what different aspects of this code is doing. Additionally, I've broken down some of this a bit further after the code and plot image.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(plotly)

# Periode <- as.Date(website$Datum)  # data not provided
# Index <-  website$KonSens
set.seed(353)
website <- data.frame(
  Periode = sample(seq(as.Date("1998-03-31"), as.Date("2022-06-30"), by = "week"), 50),
                      Index = sample(runif(100, -4.5, 2.5), 50)) %>% 
  arrange(Periode)

plot_ly(type = "scatter", mode = "markers", 
        marker = list(color = "#7AA489", size = 8,
                      line = list(width = 2, color = "#003478")),
        data = website, x = ~Periode, y = ~Index) %>% 
  add_lines(line = list(width = 5, color = "#7AA489")) %>% 
  layout(xaxis = list(dtick = "M18",         # every 18 months
                      tickformat = "%b %Y"), # Abbrev Month, 4-digit year
         yaxis = list(range = c(-6, 3),      # show this range
                      zeroline = F,          # remove horizontal line at 0
                      showline = T),         # vertical line along y-axis
         showlegend = F) %>%                 # no legend
  htmlwidgets::onRender("function(el, x){.   # make the axis titles BOLD
    gimmeX = document.querySelector('g.infolayer g.g-xtitle text');
    gimmeY = document.querySelector('g.infolayer g.g-ytitle text');
    gimmeX.style.fontWeight = 'bold';
    gimmeY.style.fontWeight = 'bold';
  }") %>% 
  rangeslider(borderwidth = 1)
```

[image]

#### Specifying the Range on the y-axis

In Plotly, you won't need to set breaks and labels. You just need to define the range. If that's all you designated in the `layout`, it would like something like this.

```
layout(yaxis = list(range = c(-6, 3))
```

#### Non-Dynamic Date x-axis Tick Text Formatting

Labels on the x-axis can be specified to be labeled by month. However, like a commenter mentioned, you loose the dynamic date scaling done when you zoom. You can actually set the scaling date format for zooming ranges, as well. (I won't go into that in this answer, though.)

To specify the labels on the x-axis as every month by month, you would use `layout.xaxis.dtick = "M1"`, every 18 months is `M18`, and so on. If you wanted to specify the appearance as the month and year, you can use the same formatting as used in `as.Date`, where `%b` is an abbreviated month name, and `%Y` is a four-digit year. If this was all you needed to set in the `layout`, it would look like this.

```
layout(xaxis = list(dtick = "M18",         # every 18 months
                    tickformat = "%b %Y")) # Abbrev Month, 4-digit year
```

#### Bold Axis Labels

Additionally, there isn't a parameter you can set to make the axis labels bold. It doesn't really matter if it's `ggplotly` or `plot_ly`.

However, you can use `htmlwidgets::onRender` to make this happen.

```
htmlwidgets::onRender("function(el, x){
    gimmeX = document.querySelector('g.infolayer g.g-xtitle text');
    gimmeY = document.querySelector('g.infolayer g.g-ytitle text');
    gimmeX.style.fontWeight = 'bold';
    gimmeY.style.fontWeight = 'bold';
  }")
```